# Any downsides to replacing REST endpoints with SignalR?

Tags: c#, rest, signalr

I'm building a fairly simple single page app. It's basically a list of items, where each item has some details, an activity log, and a current status along with some buttons to trigger actions on the server to advance the status along a workflow.

It was originally written using MVC and REST/Web API but I got stuck on the problem of keeping concurrent users up to date. For example, if User A adds an item, we want the list on User B's screen to now update to include it.

To solve this I looked into SignalR which works great. But I had a problem.

- When adding an item (using POST) the callback adds the item on the requesting client. This is fine.
- I then triggered a SignalR broadcast on the server to tell all clients about the new item. This worked fine except the local client, who now has 2 items.

I was looking into filtering the duplicate id client-side, or sending the connection id with the POST, then broadcast to all clients except the requester but it seems a bit needlessly complicated.

Instead I'm just doing this.

```
public class UpdateHub : Hub
{
    public void AddNewItem(NewItem item)
    {
        // and some server-side stuff, persist in the data store, etc
        item.trackingID = new Guid();
        item.addLogEntry("new item");
        // ...
        dataStore.addItem(item);

        // send message type and data payload
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage("add", item);
    }
}
```

**It seems a lot simpler to just get rid of all the REST stuff altogether, so am I missing anything important?**

It'll run on an intranet for a handful of users using IE11+ and I guess we do lose some commonly-understood semantics around HTTP response codes for error handling, but I don't think that's a huge deal in this situation.

Comment: Simple solution remove _When adding an item (using POST) the callback adds the item on the requesting client. This is fine._ Just add item with signalr.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve duplicate you can try to use Clients.Others inside Hub class, or AllExcept(id) if you not in the Hub class.

```
     Clients.Others.broadcastMessage("add", item);
```

In your case using SignalR shouldn`t have any downsides.

Comment: That works if I throw out the REST which I've done :) But it doesn't work in my original scenario unless I send along the id like I mentioned. It's good to hear a purely SignalR approach should work. I'd probably avoid Clients.Others as I don't want to update the caller until the server verifies the request.

Comment: I imaging you have a item array saved at you local storage client side. Why not do a ifExits check on your client side, hence you have trackingId already on your item.